# Pass liquibase parameters to gradle liquibase 'update' task

Tags: gradle, liquibase, gradle-plugin

I want to pass username, password and url liquibase parameters as a command line parameters to gradle's liquibase update task.

I have followed [liquibase-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin) to configure the plugin.
What I actually want to achieve is, pass these database parameters at runtime instead of hardcoding them in liquibase.properties file.

I can do this by exporting these three values as environment variables and access them in build.gradle. But I want to achieve this using commandline parameters.

I tried

> gradle update --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquibase_cmd_test --username=### --password=### -PrunList=main

but it gives error as

> > Unknown command-line option '--url'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that underneath gradle is Java, so you should be able to do something like this. The -D argument sets a system property.

```
gradle -Dliquibase.url=<your url> -Dliquibase.username=<username> -Dliquibase.password=<password> update -PrunList=main
```

Comment: @SteveDonie: :) I upvoted to give you credits! There should be a mechanism that hides answers to users with less than 100 reps and forces them to read on how SO works before the answer/solution is provided! Don't you think? :)